# UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol in namespace

Tags: android, cmake

I have this CMAKE file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
cmake_path(GET CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR PARENT_PATH MAIN_FOLDER)
message(MAIN_FOLDER="${MAIN_FOLDER}")

# Declares and names the project.
project("native-lib")

add_library(tensorflowlite SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
        tensorflowlite
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MAIN_FOLDER}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libtensorflowlite.so)

add_library(my_prebuilt SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
        my_prebuilt
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${MAIN_FOLDER}/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libmy_prebuilt.so)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include_files/)

add_library(
        native-lib
        SHARED
        native-lib.cpp)

find_library(
        log-lib
        log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib
        my_prebuilt
        ${log-lib}
)
```

This is the dependency tree: `native-lib -> libmy_prebuilt -> libtensorflowlite`. All the `so` files are ready in `jniLibs` folder.

This is how I load the libraries:

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("tensorflowlite");
        System.loadLibrary("my_prebuilt");
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}
```

However, because of nested dependencies, I got this error message:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZTVN6tflite17MutableOpResolverE" referenced by "/data/app/~~3RRyLtG0laiXOWXmKM3sMg==/com.your.package-wtsEbRGDpdkKMbBppc7HRg==/lib/arm64/libmy_prebuilt.so"...
```

I assume that the `libtensorflowlite` library is not linked to my prebuilt lib. Any thought?